# Casting two cantrips, both modified by metamagic?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, metamagic

Can you cast one cantrip, modifying it with "Twinned Spell" (Fire Bolt) to target 2 creatures, and then cast another cantrip as a Bonus Action (Fire Bolt), using "Quickened Spell" to target one of the previous creatures or another creature?

Answer (score 28):

#### By the Rules as Written: Yes, you can.

First: You can cast two spells, one being a cantrip (PHB, p. 202). Since both are cantrips, your example works.

> You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a
> cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

Secondly: You can only add one Metamagic option to **a** spell (PHB, p. 102). Since the wording indicates it's only limited to one per spell and not *per turn*, you can add as many Metamagic options as you wish on different spells, as long as you follow the previous rule.

> You can use only one Metamagic option on a spell when you cast it,
> unless otherwise noted.

Therefore, you can cast two *fire bolt*s, each one with a different Metamagic option.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, you can.

There is simply nothing preventing from you to do so, besides how many sorcery points you have remaining.

Comment: Rather that just stating the answer, you would be better off quoting the rule section (or at least giving their reference) to support your claim.  I agree with your statement, but without any reasoning or support, it's not really a complete answer.

Comment: @Shem Thanks for the heads up. It is hard to quote the absence of rules though.

Comment: np,  You can do what chepelink did and quote the rules that say what you can do, like only use one metamagic per casting, or can only cast a cantrip with your action if your bonus action is a spell.  Since firebolt is a cantrip, you can twin it for your action, and quicken it for your bonus action.