# Can you cast Eldritch Blast twice in the same turn using the sorcerer's Quickened Spell Metamagic option?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, spellcasting, metamagic, cantrips

Someone has been telling me that I cannot cast *eldritch blast* twice a turn, because by some rule you are only able to cast one spell and one cantrip a turn, regardless of casting time. I trust his judgment, but I want to confirm.

I have always been familiar with the stuff you get during combat: One action, one bonus action, and one reaction. It doesn't make sense that I can't use an action to cast *eldritch blast*, then use Quickened Spell to make the casting time a bonus action, and then use *eldritch blast* again.

Can you cast *eldritch blast* twice in the same turn using the sorcerer's Quickened Spell Metamagic option?

Comment: Related: "[Casting two cantrips, both modified by metamagic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93163)" and "[Can a sorcerer use the Quickened Spell metamagic option to cast cantrips?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72307)" and "[Is it possible to cast multiple spells per turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74039)" and "[Casting multiple spells in a single round](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49532)"

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Note that your friend isn't entirely wrong : you can only cast one spell and one cantrip in a turn. They're just forgetting that a cantrip *is* a spell

Comment: @PierreCathé No, the rule is that if you cast a bonus action, you can only cast cantrips during that turn. If you gain multiple Actions (e.g. due to a Fighter's Action Surge) and you don't use your Bonus Action to cast a spell, you can cast multiple spells just fine.

Comment: Little table: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133767/which-uses-of-bonus-action-spellcasting-are-legal/161422#161422

Answer (score 29):

### Two *eldritch blasts* is fine.

Step 1: Cast *eldritch blast* using Quickened Spell to make its casting time a bonus action. [You can do this.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72307/23970)

Step 2: Flip to PHB p. 203's ["Casting Time"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingTime) section and review the ["Bonus Action"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#BonusAction) subsection:

> You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

Step 3: Validate continuing usage of *eldritch blast*. Is it a cantrip? Yup. Is its casting time 1 action? Yup. ('Cause you're not quickening this one.)

Step 4: Fire away.