# Can you use meta-magic/sorcery points twice in a turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic

Example: You use *Quicken Spell* to cast a leveled spell or cantrip as a Bonus Action, you then use your Action to cast a cantrip along with using *Transmute Spell* to change the cantrip's damage type.

Is this an ok thing to do?

**LMBC:You're using two meta-magic options on two different spells in one turn.**

Comment: I think this is effectively the same as [Casting two cantrips, both modified by metamagic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93163/23970). Would you mind checking to see if that answers your question?